# Magento 2: How to set default layout to 1column

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have no idea where to set the default **layout** in creating a page in the **backend** where I want it to set the layout to **"1 Column"** instead of the default value **"Empty"**.

[image: empty layout]

Anyone have the idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override UiComponent xml file and add this code into design fieldset >> field:

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
      </item>
</argument>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Chauhan. Can you give me the path of the file that I need to  change?

Comment: Which module you want to change ?

Comment: I provide you solution for content >> page

Comment: It's for Content->Page. Yeah i want it to have the default "1 Column" so that I don't need to edit it everytime.

Comment: ok then override file :  /vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml

Comment: @nhinzky If this resolved your issue then you can mark it correct, So it can be useful for other too.

Comment: can you give me a link on how to override this specifically?

Comment: Copy that file and just paste it in your module >> view >> adminhtml >> uiComponent

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Create a UI Component XML extending file

Create `[Your_Namespace]/[Your_Module]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml`.

(Also, add `<module name="Magento_Cms"/>` to the module's `<sequence/>` in `module.xml`.)

#### 2. Insert the following code

Replace `[1column]` below without any other page_layout ID.

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="design">
        <field name="page_layout">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">[1column]</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```